# Why is the object I am dragging on screen shaking so much?

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

This what it looks like. It was recorded in 20fps. It actually shook a lot more. (The other problem is there is a invisible boundary on the right and the bottom.) I assigned a persistent ID to each pointer, so the object won't jump around when a second pointer is placed on the screen.

The implementation of onTouch() is copied from [Android dev webpage](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale). The nested class structure is taken from this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3qr1yK6u3M).

[.gif of the object shaking when I am dragging it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq0lK.gif)

This is my code:

java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private ImageView imageView;
private TextView textView;
private ViewGroup rootLayout;

private float mLastTouchX,mLastTouchY;
private final int INVALID_POINTER_ID=-1;
private float mPosX,mPosY;
int i=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    rootLayout=(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.rootView);

    imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    //imageView.setOnClickListener(this);//this thing doesn't work now
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
}

private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private int mActivePointerId=INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){
        final int action= MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
        switch(action){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {//first finger down on screen
                final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);
                final float x=MotionEventCompat.getX(event,pointerIndex);
                final float y=MotionEventCompat.getY(event,pointerIndex);

                mLastTouchX=x;
                mLastTouchY=y;

                mActivePointerId=MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event,0);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
                final int pointerIndex=MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(event,mActivePointerId);
                final float x=MotionEventCompat.getX(event,pointerIndex);
                final float y=MotionEventCompat.getY(event,pointerIndex);

                final float dx=x-mLastTouchX;
                final float dy=y-mLastTouchY;

                mPosX+=dx;
                mPosY+=dy;
                imageView.setLeft(Math.round(mPosX));
                imageView.setTop(Math.round(mPosY));

                rootLayout.invalidate();

                mLastTouchX=x;
                mLastTouchY=y;
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{//last pointer leaves the screen
                mActivePointerId=INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:{
                mActivePointerId=INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:{//when one finger leaves the screen
                final int pointerIndex=MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);
                final int pointerId=MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event,pointerIndex);
                if(pointerId==mActivePointerId){
                    final int newPointerIndex=pointerIndex==0?1:0;
                    mLastTouchX=MotionEventCompat.getX(event,newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY=MotionEventCompat.getY(event,newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId=MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }//switch
        return true;
    }//onTouch() ends
}//ChoiceTouchListener class
}
```

EDIT: -------------------------------------------------

I did what Gabe Sechan suggested. Now I cannnot even move the square. This is my code:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(event, mActivePointerId);
final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, pointerIndex);
final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, pointerIndex);

final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

if((dx*dx+dy*dy)==25){
    mPosX += dx;
    mPosY += dy;
    imageView.setLeft(Math.round(mPosX));
    imageView.setTop(Math.round(mPosY));
}
rootLayout.invalidate();

mLastTouchX = x;
mLastTouchY = y;
break;
}
```

I also created a TextView to show the dx and dy. But as soon I put in the line TextView.setText(), the square couldn't be moved:

[.gif of the TextView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CoIm.gif)

Here is my code:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(event, mActivePointerId);
final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, pointerIndex);
final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, pointerIndex);

final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;
textView.setText("dx="+dx+" dy="+dy);

mPosX += dx;
mPosY += dy;
imageView.setLeft(Math.round(mPosX));
imageView.setTop(Math.round(mPosY));

rootLayout.invalidate();

mLastTouchX = x;
mLastTouchY = y;
break;
}
```

Comment: Touches have noise in the signal.  You'll probably get better results if you make sure dx^2+dy^2 >=some threshold before counting it as an actual move. (the squaring is because we want the values to be positive, and squaring is faster than abs()).

Comment: what should the threshold be? How small is the number? What is the unit of dx?

Comment: Also why is there an invisible boundary at the right and bottom?

Comment: dx and dy are pixels.  Threshold you'll need to figure out yourself through trial and error until it feels good, but should be relatively small.  25 (5 pixels, due to squaring) would probably be a good starting point and tweak up or down from there.  Some devices will have more shake than others, of course.  So will some people-  the capacitance of human hands isn't a constant.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I did what you said, now I cannot move the square. I edited my question.

Comment: you need to look for cumulative movement, not just the movement since the last move command.  You should only be updating lastTouchX and lastTouchY when you actually move the view.

Comment: Two things:  First, I will check move event times against the down time and if less than 40 milliseconds, I won't start processing moves.  That handles the down 'slop'.  Second, I'll scale down the {x, y} coordinates to a smaller, 'logical' space that will dampen the shakey-ness.  If you need back to original, then use integer math (to drop remainders) and scale back up to original space.

Comment: You can also sample the Move events at a lower frequency by checking the times since the last move event.

Comment: Could you guys write a detailed answer?